# Copy a range of SpreadSheet to a Doc

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I copy a range of a Sheet [image] into a Doc, which I created in AppScript Editor.

Like this(Manually copied(CtrlC + CtrlV))
[image]

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is can be done.

Imagine your spreadsheet is this:
[image]

Write below code on doc's script editor,

```
function readFromSpreadsheetAndWriteOnDoc() 
{
  // get the Spreadsheet by sheet id
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1eqaThzYmTbZzP_xGTrPnTD1JX-B8rXrBrWDW8DwMNeU');
  // select the sheet
  var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('Chart');
  // get the values on selectd range
  var srcData = sourcesheet.getRange('B2:C5').getValues();

  //now your table data is on var 'srcData'

  // select this google doc
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  // select the body
  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.insertParagraph(0, 'My Title').setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  table = body.appendTable(srcData);
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);

}
```

you will get this,

[image]

Enjoy!