# Google App Script:How can I get the Sheet name from ranges

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to google app script. I am stuck in a situation. I have some ranges(created in spreadsheet) and I want to get the name of sheet associated to that ranges. The following function is on docs and I want to copy data by giving some ranges from sheet.

```
  function selectTable(sheetURL,ranges,rangevalues )
 {
  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetURL); 
  var currentSheetId=workbook.getId();


 // get the Spreadsheet by sheet id
var totalSheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(currentSheetId);

// select the sheet
var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName(rangevalues);//here i ma stuck I have ranges only and I want sheetname
var abc=sourcesheet.getNamedRanges();

 Logger.log("source sheet name-:"+sourcesheet);
  // get the values on selectd range
 var srcData = sourcesheet.getRange(ranges).getValues();
Logger.log("getting the values-:"+srcData);

 }
```

I am referring this answer 
 [Copy a range of SpreadSheet to a Doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687772/copy-a-range-of-spreadsheet-to-a-doc).

Comment: You can get the sheet from a `Range` object, but if you have only values then you must compare the every sheets values to your values to find the match (if there even is one).

Comment: @RiyafaAbdulHameed Please delete your comment to avoid misleading others that this cannot be done. It obviously can - look at the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the name of a sheet from a range object use:

```
range.getSheet().getName()
```