# After selecting a range on a Google Sheet, how do I paste the selection into a Google Doc?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-macros

I'm trying to create a macro on a Google Sheet that will select a range from the sheet and then paste the selected contents into to a Google Doc. So far I have the code to select the range:

```
function CopyToDoc() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A4:B13').activate();
}
```

Once I select the range, how do I paste it into a google doc?

Comment: About ``how do I paste it into a google doc?``, I think that more information is required. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and Document?

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687772/copy-a-range-of-spreadsheet-to-a-doc)? Do you want to copy values only?

Answer (score 0):

Well to achieve what you are saying I would do this.

```
function sheetToDoc(){

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var as = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = as.getSheets()[0];
  var temp = sh.getRange("A1:A20").getValues();

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById("DocID").getBody().appendTable(temp);

}
```

Use AppendTable() to add the information to your document in a table and appendParagraph() if you want to add the information to your document as plain text. Make test for you to know how the information will be added to your document.

I hope this helps. Greetings